# How to install stringi from local file (ABSOLUTELY no Internet Access)

Tags: r, package, stringi

I am working on a remote server using RStudio. This server has no access to the Internet. I would like to install the package "stringi." I have looked at this s[tackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553452/how-to-install-stringi-library-from-archive-and-install-the-local-icu52l-zip), but whenever I use the command

```
install.packages("stringi_0.5-5.tar.gz", 
                 configure.vars="ICUDT_DIR=/my/directory/for/icudt.zip")
```

It simply tries to access the Internet, which it cannot do. Up until now I have been using *Tools -> Install Packages -> Install from Packaged Archive File*. However, due to this error, I can no longer use this method.

How can I install this package?

Comment: do you have `devtools` installed?

Comment: Which OS is the server running with? Have you tried setting `repos = NULL` and `type = "source"` explicitly?

Comment: I am on Linux. When I set `repos = NULL` and `type = "source"` it gives me the error `icudt could not be downloaded. check your internet connectivity`. Higher up, it says `unable to resolve 'www.ibspan.waw.pl'`

Comment: I'd like to use this patch https://gist.github.com/zero323/338c8fb0faf46e5ac06d, but I don't know how. That way i could tell it to look in my local directory for the icudt.zip file, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have no internet access on local machines, you can build a distributable source package that includes all the required
ICU data files (for off-line use) by omitting some relevant lines in
the `.Rbuildignore` file. The following command sequence should do the trick:

```
wget https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/archive/master.zip -O stringi.zip
unzip stringi.zip
sed -i '/\/icu..\/data/d' stringi-master/.Rbuildignore
R CMD build stringi-master
```

Assuming the most recent development version is 1.3.1,
a file named `stringi_1.3.1.tar.gz` is created in the current working directory.
The package can now be installed (the source bundle may be propagated via
`scp` etc.) by executing:

```
R CMD INSTALL stringi_1.3.1.tar.gz
```

or by calling `install.packages("stringi_1.3.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL)`,
from within an R session.

Comment: Do you mean `R CMD INSTALL stringi-master`? (e.g as above but not with the .zip extension)

Comment: @DazedandConfused Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `unzip master.zip`? Seems the zip is just downloaded with just `master.zip` name.

Comment: @gagolews wdyt about answer provided by SeungCheol Han? looks more neat

Comment: When I run `sed -i '/\/icu..\/data/d' stringi-master/.Rbuildignore` on OSX Catalina I get the following error: `sed: 1: "stringi-master/.Rbuildi ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression`.

Comment: @Edward On MacOS use `sed -i '' '/\/icu..\/data/d' stringi-master/.Rbuildignore` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592391)

Answer (score 8):

For a Linux machine the easiest way is from my point of view:

1. Download the release you need from [Rexamine](https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/releases) in tar.gz format to your local pc. In opposition to the version on CRAN it already contains the icu55\data\ folder.
2. Move the archive to your target linux machine without internet access
3. run `R CMD INSTALL stringi-1.0-1.tar.gz` (in case of release 1.0-1)

Comment: Confirming steps above worked perfectly in June 2021, on Redhat 7.9.   Thankyou for sharing this!

Comment: @sparco1500 always surprised how long such things last ;)

Answer (score 6):

You provided the wrong value of configure.vars.
It indicates that you have to give the directory's name, not a final file name.

Correct your code to the following:

```
install.packages("stringi_0.5-5.tar.gz", 
                 configure.vars="ICUDT_DIR=/my/directory/for/")
```

Regards,
Sean

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below

1. Download `icudt55l.zip` seperately from server where you have internet access with
   `wget http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/~gagolews/stringi/icudt55l.zip`
2. Copy the downloaded packages to the server where you want to install `stringi`
3. Execute the following command
   `R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='ICUDT_DIR=/tmp/ALL' stringi_1.1.6.tar.gz`

`icudt55l.zip` is copied to `/tmp/ALL`

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from @gagolews almost worked for me. Here's what actually did the trick with ***RStudio***.

1. Download [the `master.zip` file that will save as `stringi-master.zip`](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/archive/master.zip).
2. Unzip the file onto your desktop. The unzipped folder should be `stringi-master`.
3. Edit the `.Rbuildignore` file by removing `^src/icu55/data` and `^src/icu61/data` or similar lines.
4. Move the folder from your desktop to the home directory of your server.
5. Create a **New Project** in RStudio with `~/stringi-master` as the **Existing Directory**
6. From RStudio's menu, select **Build** and **Build Source Package**. (You may need to first select **Configure Build Tools**. For **Project build tools** choose **Package** then select **OK**.)
7. It should create a `tar.gz` file, in the following format: `stringi_x.x.(x+1).tar.gz`. For example, if the current version of stringi is 1.5.3, it will create version 1.5.4. (I received a few warnings that didn't seem to affect the outcome.)
8. Move the newly created package to your local repository. Update the repository index. And install the package.